# where should I put my .desktop files in kde plasma?

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, .desktop, plasma-5, kde5

In the Gnome desktop environment I can create a shortcut to an application by placing the .desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/, like this:

```shell
cat > ~/.local/share/applications/vscode.desktop <<EOL
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/media/data/sas/devel/opt/code/code %f
Icon=/media/data/sas/devel/opt/code/visual-studio-code-green.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=vscode
Comment=Editor for building and debugging modern web and cloud applications
Categories=Development;WebDevelopment;IDE;Utility;TextEditor;
EOL
```

That way I can press the Meta key and just start typing "code" to then select and run the application.

How can I achieve the same within KDE Plasma 5?

Using Kubuntu 18.04, KDE Plasma 5.12.7, KDE framework 5.44

---

edit: just had to create the folder and everything worked as expected, sorry...

Comment: Why not? What happens when you try, assuming you've made the .desktop file executable and the name is unique.

Comment: It should be the same.

Comment: sorry, the directory just wasn't there, in ubuntu (gnome) it's always there by default... I created it and everything worked fine... I googled around but couldn't find an example for kde...

Comment: It doesn't exist in Kubuntu 19.04. I guess the same applies to Kubuntu 18.04 as well but I can't remember!

Answer (score 16):

Global application launch files ending ".desktop" go in:

`/usr/share/applications`

Personal application files go in:

`/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/`